# Таблицы sql. Уникальные значения

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, дата

```
Create table Patient(
Fullname varchar(55) not null,
Phone varchar(13) not null,
Birthday date,
DataMetting date,
Notice varchar(1000),
primary key(Fullname,Phone)
);

Create table Specialist(
Fullname varchar(55) not null,
Phone varchar(13) not null,
Birthday date,
Education varchar(1000),
DateToWork date,
primary key(Fullname,Phone)
);

insert into SPECIALIST(PHONE , FULLNAME , EDUCATION, BIRTHDAY) values ('011','A','vuz1','1996-AUG-24');
insert into SPECIALIST(PHONE , FULLNAME , EDUCATION) values ('323','B','vuz2');
```

Появляется ошибка

```
Error report -
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C0011799) violated
```

Перевод её ясен, а суть немного нет. И еще проблема, почему то не добавляется дата. СУБД Oracle.

Спасибо !

Comment: Таблица Specialist до INSERT пустая была?

Comment: да, до добавления, она была пустой, я же её выше создал

Comment: На пустой таблице эти два инсерта происходят (только что проверил). Правда первый insert приходится поправить, потому как у вас поле тип а date и строку туда вставлять нельзя. Возникает вопрос куда же вы вставляете строки, если первый insert должен привести к ошибке

Comment: я его удалял)) и вставлял без него, не знаю как добавить дату, и через to_date пытался, и кучу разных выражений перепробовал.

Comment: @Влад, даже так? TO_DATE('1996-AUG-24','RRRR-MON-DD')